# anybody can help me to come out this probleam

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bundler

Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart.git' "/home/ubuntu/.bundler/cache/git/remotipart-46f8bf276d5ffef4f196efc85f86445ee22983a2" --bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /home/ubuntu/Desktop/1_files/imageeditorservicespro has failed.

Comment: source 'https://rubygems.org'gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

Answer (score 1):

Your git apparently doesn't have the curl bindings which are required for http/https cloning.
You can change your gemfile to use `git://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart.git` explicitly instead of just `github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart.git` (the git:// part is important)

Alternatively, if you want a git version that can handle http, try re-installing git with curl via aptitude or from source:

Via apt:

```
sudo apt-get remove git-core
apt-get install curl libcurl4-openssl-dev # or whatever your curl dev package is
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

From sources:

```
sudo apt-get remove git-core
sudo apt-get build-dep git-core

# download and extract the git sources from https://github.com/git/git/tags
# cd into the source directory
./configure --with-curl --with-expat
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: thanks paukul .after this git clone git://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart.git
 then my code is working

Comment: you're welcome. if my answer helped you please accept it as the right answer

Comment: but i could not understand that when i was writing gem 'remotipart', :git => "github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart.git" it was not working but when i wright gem 'remotipart', :git => "github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart.git",branch=>'master' then it begin to work could u explain why?

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want to clone it

```
 git clone git://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart.git
```

Comment: i did use it it create clone but when i bundle install same error with fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Comment: gem 'haml'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.3.4'
gem 'remotipart', :git => "https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart.git"
gem 'activeadmin'
gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre' # required by activeadmin
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'launchy'
end

Comment: thanks skywOOker after this i did some changes on gem file and now it is working

Comment: but i could not understand that when i was writing gem 'remotipart', :git => "github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart.git" it was not working but when i wright gem 'remotipart', :git => "github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart.git",branch=>'master' then it begin to work could u explain why?